# Custom Resource Lambda should run on Create but instead runs on first Update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-requests.html#crpg-ref-request-fields) (See: RequestType) a custom Lambda function can be triggered by CloudFormation operations of the types: `create-stack`, `update-stack`, or `delete-stack` operations.

My lambda is configured to only do its task on `create-stack`, but when I added this Custom Resource and Lambda to my (pre-existing) CloudFormation stack and updated it, the lambda ran as if the stack was created, even though it was updated.
Should it not run only for the first create? Why would it work for the first update?

Note: It did not run for subsequent updates

###### Relevant Code Snippets

CloudFormation Resources:

```yaml
LambdaUpdateNodeStatusFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaUpdateNodeStatusFunctionName
      CodeUri: ../../../bin/handlers/espnode/lambdaupdatenodesstatus_c
      Handler: lambdaupdatenodesstatus
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaUpdateNodeStatusExecutionRole.Arn
      MemorySize: 512 #MB
      Timeout: 900

  LambdaUpdateNodeStatusFunctionLog:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Join ["", ["/aws/lambda/", !Ref LambdaUpdateNodeStatusFunctionName]]
  
  LambdaUpdateNodeStatusCustomResource:
    Type: Custom::LambdaUpdateNodeStatusCustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt LambdaUpdateNodeStatusFunction.Arn
      Version: !Ref BuildVersion
```

Lambda Code:

```golang
type CustomLambdaRequest struct {
    RequestType        string `json:"RequestType"`
    ResponseURL        string `json:"ResponseURL"`
    StackId            string `json:"StackId"`
    RequestId          string `json:"RequestId"`
    ResourceType       string `json:"ResourceType"`
    LogicalResourceId  string `json:"LogicalResourceId"`
    PhysicalResourceId string `json:"PhysicalResourceId"`
}

func Handler(customLambdaRequest CustomLambdaRequest) {

    if customLambdaRequest.RequestType == "Create" {
        // Do some processing here
    } else {
        // Do Nothing here
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to share your template and lambda code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lambda-backed custom resources are triggered, as you mentioned, in the `create-stack`, `update-stack`, and `delete-stack` operations.

But they are triggered for each custom resource that is part of your template.

That means that when you add a new `Custom::` resource to your template, it will call the lambda with `RequestType == Create` and save the `LogicalResourceId` in the cloud formation state. Later when you update the stack it will trigger the function with the update request type and so on.

Comment: So basically for all intents and purposes, the triggers are not create/update/delete-stack, but create/update/delete-customResource?

Comment: the simple answer is yes! but the site does not allow me to answer with a single word with less than 10 chars.